# Outlook Redemption MAPITable ExecSQL

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

When querying a MAPITable (created from GAL with about 200000 entries) I get an Outlook Interop exception: IMAPITable::Restrict: MAPI_E_TOO_COMPLEX.

The query works if ExecSQL query is : "Select * from folder".

When i try to query with "SELECT * from Folder Where CompanyName = 'Countryname'" the exception occurs.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Morten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most address book providers (unlike store providers) support very limited set of restrictions. The only thing guaranteed to work is a `PR_ANR` restriction (which Outlook requires). For the GAL provider, you can use `PR_SEARCH` exposed by the [RDOAddressListSearch](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressListSearch.htm) object (new for Redemption 5.7).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I tried it out, but I can not use this for search unless i know the exact text of the field. (Ex. In our Company column we have "xxxxx xxxxxx - CountryName") And I would search for CountryName But there's no "Like" operator is there?

Comment: No, it only searches for a prefix. This is the same as the search dialog in a GAL container in Outlook.